# How do I vertically center these objects in React JS?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, frontend, vertical-alignment, web-development-server

I'm really struggling with alignment here; I've spent hours looking online but to no avail. The circle, "Welcome to" text and rectangle are too far apart from each other like in the image below
[image]

But I would like for them to be like this, so that the user would not need to scroll down
[image]

Any help is appreciated.

I have tried the

```
justifyContent: 'center',
alignItems: 'center',
```

properties, along with many more, but it still does not work.

Comment: It is difficult to help without seeing your code. Please provide what you've done so far

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know your actual saturation so i give an simple example

```
<div class='parent'>
<div>Child 1</div>
<div>Child 2</div>
<div>Child 3</div>
</div>

:css
.parent{
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need `flex` for centering text or image, just use `text-align` property.
Tag `<img>` and text have display `inline` by default. The property `text-align` using for horizontal aligning `inline` elements.

Info: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/text-align

```css
.centered-div {
  text-align: center; 
}

img {
  width: 300px;
}
```

```html
<section>
  <div class='centered-div'>Hello World!</div>
  <div class='centered-div'>
    <img src='https://cdn.logo.com/hotlink-ok/logo-social.png' alt='logo' />
  </div>
  <div class='centered-div'>
    <img src='https://banner2.cleanpng.com/20180203/ihw/kisspng-line-black-and-white-angle-point-bold-line-cliparts-5a75a3b3c7c9b8.7740503415176590598183.jpg' alt='bottom' />
  </div>
</section>
```